# Problems with controlling LED with soil moisture sensor

Tags: sensors, led

I'm a beginner at Arduino.

I have a soil moisture sensor and I mapped the lowest and highest moisture value to a value in between 0 and 100.

What I was trying to do was if the value was less than 50, then the LED should turn on. But even when the value was less than 50 (e.g 25) the LED doesn't turn on.

The moisture detection or the value mapping works perfectly fine.

Does the issue lie on my code or my LED wiring?
[image]

Code:

```cpp
int mostMoist = 180;
int leastMoist = 600;
int percent;
int raw;
const int threshold = 50;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  raw = analogRead(A0);
  percent = map(raw,leastMoist,mostMoist,0,100);

  if (percent < 0){
    percent = 0;
  }

  if (percent < threshold){
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN,HIGH);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN,LOW);
  }

  Serial.println(percent);
  delay(2);  
}
```

Comment: load and run LED blink code to test the LED

Comment: problem aside: you should only switch on power to the sensor when you're about to do a reading; a constant charge will corrode the sensor's metal very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

A good way to start debugging this sort of problem is to print out debug statements that say what the hardware should be doing. If the debug statements print out as expected then it's probably hardware, if not, then it's probably your code, e.g.

```
if (percent < threshold){
  Serial.prinln("LED on.");
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN,HIGH);
}
else {
  Serial.prinln("LED off.");
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN,LOW);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, everything's working fine after adding the debug statement, the LED's turning on at the right time!

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help. If that answers your question you may want to mark the answer as accepted: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers